# RavenDB Session > 30

Tags: c#, ravendb, document-database

If I'm trying to save a list of items I want to save that has a count > 30 I get an error saying

> The maximum number of requests (30)
>   allowed for this session has been
>   reached. Raven limits the number of
>   remote calls that a session is allowed
>   to make as an early warning system.
>   Sessions are expected to be short
>   lived, and  Raven provides facilities
>   like Load(string[] keys) to load
>   multiple documents at once and batch
>   saves.

What can I do to get around this? The problem with this error is I'm not loading, I'm trying to save documents. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Call Session.Store with each of your objects before you call Session.SaveChanges.

Comment: I called session Session.SaveChanges out side of my 'foreach' and it worked perfectly

Comment: You've been noticed: http://ayende.com/blog/4814/ravendb-safe-by-default-design-ndash-it-works. Perhaps you should rethink.

Comment: Hmm... Monitoring `(Session as Raven.Client.Document.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations).NumberOfRequests` property told me that the number is raising on each `SaveChanges()` call (call it after `Session.Store`) and fails on reaching `MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession`... I'm using RavenDb 3.5 and still puzzled by what is resetting this number...

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Although not recommended, in special cases, you can set the **Session.Advanced.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession** property.

```
using (var docStore = store.Initialize())
   {
     using (var session = docStore.OpenSession())
      {
         session.Advanced.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession = 100;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Upvoted as there are legitimate reasons you might want to set this higher. 1000 is perhaps too much. 

A legitimate reason might be you are doing a number of transactions, but only want to fail if one save fails.

The error is to warn devs from doing something stupid.

Comment: where to place that code???
means to say that place it when the connection is initialized or when opening session

Comment: Small increase of `MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession` (e.g. up to 100) can be justified, but a need of a bigger number, should be treated as a red flag and may indicate necessity to rethink your approach.