# Saving a Twitter Sample Stream to RavenDB results in the exception The maximum number of requests (30) allowed for this session has been reached

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am attempting to save a Twitter sample stream to RavenDB but I am encountering the exception: "The maximum number of requests (30) allowed for this session has been reached."

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411037/ravendb-session-30) question has the same problem however I *think* by calling `session.Store` I am already doing what the accepted answer suggests.

I know I am doing something wrong but not sure what.

Here is my code:

```
using Tweetinvi;

namespace TwitterNoSql
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Auth.SetUserCredentials() // redacted for SO

            var stream = Stream.CreateSampleStream();

            using (var session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
            {
                stream.TweetReceived += (sender, theTweet) =>
                {
                    var tm = new TwitterModels
                    {
                        Id = theTweet.Tweet.Id,
                        TheTextFromTwitter = theTweet.Tweet.FullText
                    };

                    session.Store(tm);
                    session.SaveChanges();

                };
                stream.StartStream();

            }                
        }                        
    }
}
```

DocumentStoreHolder.cs

```
using System;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Document;

namespace TwitterNoSql
{
    class DocumentStoreHolder
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IDocumentStore> LazyStore =
            new Lazy<IDocumentStore>(() =>
            {
                var store = new DocumentStore
                {
                    Url = "http://localhost:8080",
                    DefaultDatabase = "TwitterNoSql"
                };
                return store.Initialize();
            });

        public static IDocumentStore Store =>
             LazyStore.Value;
    }
}
```

TwitterModels.cs

```
namespace TwitterNoSql
{
    public class TwitterModels
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string TheTextFromTwitter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a single document session, and using that for *all* tweets that are received. So, if you receive 5000 tweets over the span of an hour, you'll hit this issue.

Two ways to fix this:

1. If TweetReceived is sparse (e.g. it fires a few times a minute or less), then just create a new Raven session each time the tweet is received.
2. If TweetReceived is fired a bunch of times in quick succession (e.g. 5000 tweets received in a few seconds), then use Raven [BulkInsert](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/bulk-insert/how-to-work-with-bulk-insert-operation).

**Option #1**, session for each tweet received:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Auth.SetUserCredentials() // redacted for SO

    var stream = Stream.CreateSampleStream();
    stream.TweetReceived += (sender, theTweet) =>
    {
        var tm = new TwitterModels
        {
            Id = theTweet.Tweet.Id,
            TheTextFromTwitter = theTweet.Tweet.FullText
        };

        using (var session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
        { 
           session.Store(tm);
           session.SaveChanges();
        }
    };
    stream.StartStream();             
}
```

**Option #2**, using Bulk Insert:

```
using (BulkInsertOperation bulkInsert = store.BulkInsert())
{
   stream.TweetReceived += (sender, theTweet) =>
   {
       var tm = new TwitterModels
       {
           Id = theTweet.Tweet.Id,
           TheTextFromTwitter = theTweet.Tweet.FullText
       };


       bulkInsert.Store(tm);
   }
};
```

Either will work here. Use #1 if Tweets arrive sparsely over the lifetime of the app. Use #2 if tweets arrive all at once in bulk.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling SaveChanges() at the end of your operation:

```
using (var session = DocumentStoreHolder.Store.OpenSession())
{
    stream.TweetReceived += (sender, theTweet) =>
    {
        var tm = new TwitterModels
        {
            Id = theTweet.Tweet.Id,
            TheTextFromTwitter = theTweet.Tweet.FullText
        };

        session.Store(tm);

    };

    stream.StartStream();
    session.SaveChanges();  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a very large set of data, you probably don't want to do it using the session, a bulk insert would work better here.